# While firing the Purchase event not showing duplicates event

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-pixel, facebook-conversions-api

I am using the Facebook pixel and Facebook conversion API. to fire the event viewPage and viewContent etc. everything is working fine. but the issue when I fired Purchase event at that time event_id is same but that is not showing duplicate like other. I have attached that screenshot that can make you understand.
[image]